# Getting data having only same values in all rows in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 tables in DB2:

```
1) users ==> basic user details

2) details ==> more user details
```

The "details" table has columns named ssn, company and super_company. The company and super_company column can have multiple values for the same SSN.

**Problem:** I am trying to fetch only the users which has same super_company for the ssn.

I need username,ssn and company_id in output.

I tried grouping but not sure how to proceed as I am new to DB2.

**SQL Fiddle:** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d378/1/0

Please note that sql fiddle does not support DB2. I have provided just for providing the table structure.

Comment: In your fiddle, what is thje expected result?

Comment: Account Id of 100 and 200 is the expected as they both have same company_id for them.

Comment: You want users that "has same super_company"? Same super_company as what?

Comment: No.. Users who has only 1 unique super_company.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query

```
select U.account_id, U.username from users U
  join details D
    on U.account_id = D.account_id
group by U.account_id, U.username
having count(distinct super_company) = 1
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f096e/2)

Comment: I would need username,ssn,and company in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you want `company` in the output, but you do not say what to do when there are multiple companies.  Here is one method that outputs one row per user with an arbitrary company:

```
select u.username, u.accound_id, d.ssn as ssn,
       min(d.company) as company, min(d.super_company)
from users u join
     details d
     on u.accound_id = d.accound_id
group by u.username, u.accound_id
having min(d.super_company) = max(d.super_company);
```

Actually aggregating multiple `company` values into a string is harder than it should be in DB2.  You can get the individual records for matching users as well.  I would do this using window functions:

```
select username, accound_id, ssn, company, super_company
from (select u.username, d.*,
             min(super_company) over (partition by ssn) as minsc,
             max(super_company) over (partition by ssn) as maxsc
      from users u join
           details d
           on u.accound_id = d.accound_id
     ) t
where minsc = maxsc;
```

This is closer to your specific question, which is about duplicates by `ssn`, because it does not include `username` and `accound_id` when looking for duplicates.

Comment: regarding your comment on "aggregating multiple company ... is harder ...", are you familiar with LISTAGG that where introduced in 9.7?

Comment: @Lennart . . . I think the last time I suggested `LISTAGG()` on DB2, the OP was using an earlier version.  But you are right for more recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.*, u.* 
from details d
join users u
    on u.accound_id = d.accound_id
join (
    select accound_id
    from details
    group by accound_id
    having count(distinct super_company) = 1
) x
   on x.accound_id = u.accound_id
```